# Jenkins behind nginx forwarding port 8081 --> 8081 not working

Tags: docker, nginx, jenkins, reverse-proxy

I am running Jenkins in a Docker container and configured nginx (running in another container) to act as a reverse proxy. My goal is to make Jenkins (listening on port `8080` in its container) accessible on port `8081` on the host on which the Docker engine is running.

So what I basically want to do is use nginx to forward all requests to `localhost:8081` to `jenkins-docker-container:8080`

Basically all works fine, but Jenkins seems to redirect to `localhost`(without a port) from time to time. Here's what I did:

- I set `http://localhost:8081` as the Jenkins URL in the Jenkins config
- I use the following nginx jenkins configuration:

  ```
  server {
      listen       8081;
      server_name  "localhost";

      access_log off;

      location / {
          proxy_pass         http://jenkins-master:8080;
          proxy_redirect     http://jenkins-master:8080 $scheme://localhost:8081;

          proxy_set_header   Host              $host;
          proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
          proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto http;
          proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Port  8081;
          proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

          proxy_connect_timeout      150;
          proxy_send_timeout         100;
          proxy_read_timeout         100;

          proxy_buffer_size          8k;
          proxy_buffers              4 32k;
          proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
          proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;

      }

  }
  ```
- here is my Docker Swarm configuration

  ```
    jenkinsmaster:
      build: jenkins-master
      image: michaellihs/jenkins
      ports:
        - 50000:50000
      secrets:
        - jenkins-user
        - jenkins-pass
      volumes:
        - jenkinsdata:/var/log/jenkins
        - jenkinsconf:/var/jenkins_home
        - jenkinsjobs:/var/jenkins_jobs
      networks:
        nw001:
          aliases:
            - jenkins-master

    jenkinsnginx:
      build: jenkins-nginx
      image: michaellihs/jenkinsnginx
      ports:
        - 8081:8081
      networks:
        - nw001
  ```

Any ideas how I could get this fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure you should be using `proxy_redirect`. We have Jenkins set without it and everything works fine, like so:

```
location / {
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_pass http://jenkins:8080;
}
```

I have just checked our setup - we did no further config tweaks on Jenkins side (like ones tomcat for Jira would need), so your redirects are probably caused by that `proxy_redirect` option.

Comment: thanks for your response - I tried without as well.. no changes... problem is, that it "loses" the port - so maybe things work fine, as long as Jenkins is accessed on port 80...

Comment: What do you mean by it loses the port? Maybe it's not a docker/nginx problem, but rather a Jenkins' one? Maybe it stops listening on the port for some reason? Have you checked the logs?

Comment: It means that sometimes I get redirected from localhost:8081 to localhost (port 80). This happens when I send a form - e.g. in the global configuration. So I guess, Jenkins thinks it‘s running on port 80 and renders links for this port.